# Cycle Index of Edges of a Square

Tags: combinatorics

Find the cycle index for the group of symmetries of a square in terms of permutations of edges, not corners.

Workings:

There are the $0^o, 90^o, 180, 270^o$ rotations. There are the reflections in the horizontal axis, vertical axis, diagonal reflection (axis from top left to bottom right), diagonal reflection (axis from top right to bottom left).

The $0^o$ rotation gives $(a)(b)(c)(d)$.

The $90^o$ rotation gives $(abcd)$.

The $180^o$ rotation gives $(ac)(bd)$.

The $270^o$ rotation gives $(adcb)$.

The horizontal axis gives $(ad)(b)(c)$.

The vertical axis gives $(bd)(a)(c)$

The reflection from the top left to bottom right axis gives $(ad)(bc)$

The reflection from the top right to bottom left axis gives $(ab)(dc)$

So the cycle representations are

$0^o$ is $x_1^4$

$90^o$ is $x_4$

$180^o$ gives $x_2^2$

$270^o$ gives $x_4$

Horizontal axis gives $x_2x_1^2$

Vertical axis gives $x_2x_1^2$

Top left to bottom right gives $x_2^2$

Top right to bottom left gives $x_2^2$

Summing all these gives

$N = \frac{1}{8}(x_1^4 + 2x_4 + 2x_2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2)$

I'm wondering if I did this correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you have is correct if you are describing those diagonal reflections the way I am thinking you are saying. I would suggest explaining that more clearly though. Perhaps draw a tiny diagram of the reflection you are doing.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.